# How to prove that Linear Transformation cannot preserve independence

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, independence

I know how to prove linear transformation can preserve dependence, but how to prove the converse without using a counter example?

Comment: Why "without a counterexample"? Take a zero map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because some of the vectors may in the null space of the domain, e.g. $\textsf{V}$, of a linear transformation, e.g. $\textsf{T}:\textsf{V}\to\textsf{W}$. You can't promise that any independent subset of $\textsf{V}$ won't contain a element $v'$ such that $\textsf{T}(v')=0_\textsf{W}$

Comment: That's the point. I've been struggling with it for too long. I always think 0 implies T(0). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about to use $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$? Determinant is zero equivalent to linear dependence of columns.